# url-friendly username function, that checks in db, if it is unique

Tags: php, codeigniter, loops

I am trying to make a function in codeigniter that makes a username "url-friendly". It has to make it all lowercase, replace danish characters `æ, ø, å with ae, oe, aa` and then do a database check if it's unique, if for example there was a user named `ægir` and one named `aegir`. If it already exists, I just want to prepend a number, and then do the check again.

This is what i have so far:

```
public function url_username($username)
{
    for($i = 1, "What should i write here?", "What about here?")
    {
        $url_username = str_replace(array('æ','ø','å'),array('ae','oe','aa'),strtolower($username));
        $this->db->select('url_username')->from('users')->where('url_username',$username);
        $q = $this->db->get();

        if($q > 0)
        {
            "what should i write here?"
        }
    }
}
```

If someone could help me finish this up, I would appreciate it.

Comment: what you are writing there now ?

Comment: You need help for `for` syntax? What are you looping over?  It seems username is a string not an array, so why is there a loop at all?

Comment: Because it needs to check database again after having prepended a number, and then break out of the loop when the database does not return a row. I understand the "for" syntax, but its more of how i can put it to use with my function.

Comment: Not that it has to be a for loop, it can also be a while

Comment: You don't need the `for` loop - or *any* loop. Just update your query to return the records that start with the sanitized `url_username` - you can then increment the largest one if you've ordered it descending.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public function url_username($username)
{
    $url_username = str_replace(array('æ','ø','å'),array('ae','oe','aa'),strtolower($username));

    $this->db->select('url_username');
    $this->db->from('users');
    $this->db->like('url_username', $url_username, 'after');
    $this->db->order_by('url_username', 'desc');
    $this->db->limit(1);
    $q = $this->db->get();

    if($q->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        // increment the username with the String Helper
        $this->load->helper('string');
        $url_username = increment_string($q->url_username, '_');
    }
    return $url_username;
}
```

OK, so we just change the query to look for anything that starts with the sanitized `url_username`. We use the `like` statement for that, then we order by the `url_username` descending (meaning `myusername_3` is before `myusername_2` in the result set). Then we just return the first row (because it will be the largest incremented value) -- we then just increment the end with the [String Helper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/string_helper.html).

Comment: Just to be sure, if i had a user named ægær(aegaer) and aegær(aegaer_2) and i then try to make aegaer, it would return aegaer_3?

Comment: yes, look at the docs of the `increment_string` function in the [String Helper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/string_helper.html). --- (from the docs page) echo increment_string('file', '_'); // returns "file_1"  ---   
echo increment_string('file', '-', 2); // returns "file-2"  ---   
echo increment_string('file-4'); // returns "file-5"

Answer (score 1):

Little modification to @swatkins answer. It's possible tha aegir and aegir1 both exists in your db so you'd want to keep incrimenting the number afterwards to make sure you have a username that is unique.

```
public function url_username($username)
{
    $url_username = str_replace(array('æ','ø','å'),array('ae','oe','aa'),strtolower($username));
    $this->db->select('url_username')->from('users')->like('url_username', $url_username, 'after');
    $q = $this->db->get();


    if($q->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        $this->load->helper('string');
        return $this->url_username(increment_string($q->url_username, '-', $i));
    }

    return $url_username;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand that this recursive solution is better. How does my solution not handle the "aegir" and "aegir1" use case? In the case that the returned username is "aegir", my solution would return "aegir_1". In the case the returned username is "aegir1", my solution would return "aegir1_1". In the case the returned username is "aegir_3", my solution would return "aegir_4".

Comment: I had it all typed out before you posted, just hadn't clicked submit yet. =) Personal preference. First, I think that aegir_2 is looks cleaner than aegir1_1. Second, what happens if both aegir, aegir1, and aegir1_1 exist in his database? Your code makes an assumption that, if the username is aegir1, that aegir1_1 doesn't exist in the database when it's possible that aegir1_1 is already taken. The recursion guarantees uniqueness without making assumption.

Comment: From what i understand the string helper would not make aegir1_1, but aegir_2 instead

Comment: Ok, but that still doesn't solve the problem if aegir_2 already being taken. You'd want to check your database to make sure that aegir_2 is available, rather than just assuming it is available. That's why I suggested the recession since it checks to make sure the value of incriment_string is available.

Comment: You are assuming that aegir and aegir1 are the same username and not unique. I would treat those as separate usernames since the system uses the convention of `username - underscore - incremented value`. Therefore, aegir1 should increment to aegir1_1 and aegir would increment to aegir_1. So the only change would be the incremented value **after** the underscore.